# Weblogic10.3, packaging tagfile in jar got tag handler class was not found

Tags: weblogic, tagfile

My war is working on Tomcat6, but got error on Weblogic10.3:
The tag handler class was not found "jsp_servlet.*tags.*__tag"

Here is the situation:
I have developed 5 tag files, and define these 5 tag file in one tld,
and package them into nnn.jar with tld.
My first JSP is using 2 of 5 tag files, when I click this page,
in tomcat, it's working well,but in Weblogic10.3, got error above,
I found the key factor of this error is "using 2 of 5 tag",because that when I'm using all 5 tag files in one JSP, the Weblogic103 is working well!
So I think maybe this's a weblogic bug or I need do some configuration to avoid this.
Any idea about this situation? thans a lot!

Comment: I have the same error in weblogic 11g. When I visit the webapplication page for the first time I get the error. Refreshing the page fixes the problem.